# Difference between promise.then() or .then()

Tags: react-native, promise

In react-native what is the difference between

```
.promise.then()
```

and just

```
.then()
```

How do I know when to use one over the other? They both seem to be invoked after the previous chained function has finished.

Comment: .promise.then() means what to do when promise is resolved/rejected/pending. resolve/rejected/pending are the states of promise. .then() is a function that returns the promise. These both methods are used to convert asynchronous function to synchronous function.

Comment: `These both methods are used to convert asynchronous function to synchronous function` - do not listen to this talk of sorcery. Rule 37: You can not make asynchronous code synchronous. Think of synchronous code being coffee beans on a coffee plant and asynchronous code being your morning caffè latte. You can harvest, dry, roast  and grind the beans, add water and milk to make the latte, however, once you have the latte, you can't extract the living beans from it

Comment: Not directly related to your question but react native supports es7 `async `/`await` syntax a much cleaner syntax for handling asynchronous code in javascript you should check it out https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: @Maxwelll Thank you, I appreciate the info! I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon what the function you are calling returns.  If it returns a promise, then you can use `.then()` on the return value directly.

If it doesn't return a promise, but instead returns some sort of object, then you can sometimes (depending upon the object returned) use `.promise` to retrieve a promise that represents the async operation you just initiated.

If you showed a more complete code example(s), we could advise about those specific code examples more specifically.

Comment: In the examples here: https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs most of the examples use just .then, but the uploadFiles function uses .promise.then.

Comment: @kojow7 - That's because exactly what I said, `uploadFiles()` returns an object.  From their doc: `downloadFile and uploadFiles return an object of the form { jobId: number, promise: Promise }`.  They don't return a promise so you have to get the promise from the return value before you can use it.  You just have to read the documentation or look at their code to see what something returns to know how to use it.

Comment: So, just to clarify, the uploadFiles function is returning both a jobId number as well as a promise both contained within an object? So it is returning a promise but the promise is encapsulated inside the object?

Comment: @kojow7 - Yes, it's returning an object that has a promise (and some other stuff) in it so if you want the promise, you have to reach into the object to get it.  Other functions return only a promise so you can just use the return result directly as a promise.

Comment: Great, thank you, that makes sense! I have tried looking in the official react-native docs and searching for other sites but could not find this information. Is there a better place that has complete documentation about such things? So far I've found bits and pieces spread on different sites but no cohesive set of documentation.